# Problem with converting string to char* in a function

Tags: c++, string, char

In my code, my inout is `string`, but one of my functions works with `char*`, so I'm converting it like this:

```
string Regex;
std::cin>>Regex;
const char* char_regex = Regex.c_str();
```

And my function:

```
Regex(automates_list,Regex.size(),char_regex,std::cout);
```

which is defined like this:

```
void Regex(List& list,int const& word_length,const char* word,ostream& out)
```

The error is :

> error: no match for call to '(std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}) (List&, int&, const char*&, std::ostream&)'|

Comment: The second parameter to your function is `int const& word_length`, you're passed argument is `Regex.c_str()`. They don't match, and there is no overload that does match. The error message is accurate. In short, you're missing the second argument.

Comment: Thank you,I  edited it with Regex.size() but it's neither working

Comment: Dare we ask what the error is *now* ? Your post should be amended with any changes or updates, and the resulting errors you're still receiving.

Comment: Sorry,I edited it.

Comment: Name your variable something besides `Regex`. The compiler is trying to execute a function operator `operator ()(List&, int&,  const char*&, std::ostream&)` on your `std::string`variable `Regex` because it's name hides the API of the same name.

Comment: Thank you!It's working!

Comment: The error does not appear to match your function prototype. The error says: `List&, int&, const char*&, std::ostream&` and the function you printed says `void Regex(List& list,int const& word_length,const char* word,ostream& out)` - where the error complains about `const char*&` and the function has a `const char*` is `Regex(...)` your function and is it copy/pasted correctly? - maybe you can paste the whole class and the whole code including `automates_list` variable etc...  so then we can also run and test it? (this is probably why people are voting to close the question (not enough info)

Comment: ok -  never mind! - by the time I wrote my comment WhozCraig had already sussed it out : )

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your code looks something like this:

```
void Regex(...); 

int main() {
    std::string Regex = ...;
    // ...

    Regex(automates_list,Regex.size(),char_regex,std::cout);
}
```

You're getting an error because the string `Regex` [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the function `Regex`. You can get around this by either renaming the string, or renaming the function:

**Renaming the function:** Here I renamed the function to `applyRegex`.

```
void applyRegex(...); 

int main() {
    std::string Regex = ...;
    // ...

    applyRegex(automates_list,Regex.size(),char_regex,std::cout);
}
```

**Renaming the string:** Here I renamed the string to `userRegex`.

```
void Regex(...); 

int main() {
    std::string userRegex = ...;
    // ...

    Regex(automates_list,userRegex.size(),char_regex,std::cout);
}
```